# Как вывести переменную из цикла for в массив? C#

Tags: c#, обработка-ошибок

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы вывести номера 3-х месяцев, где прибыль меньше чем 0. Этот код выводит только последний месяц, где прибыль меньше чем 0 трижды.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] expenses = new int[12];
        int[] receipts = new int[12];

        Random r = new Random();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Месяц", 10} {"Доход, тыс. руб", 20} {"Расход, тыс. руб", 20} {"Прибыль", 10}");
        int profit;
        int[] badProfit = new int[3];
       

        for (int k = 0; k<12; k++)
        {
            expenses[k] = r.Next(0, 100_000);
            receipts[k] = r.Next(0, 100_000);
            profit = receipts[k] - expenses[k];
            
            
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            if(profit>0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
            if(profit<0)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m <=2;m++)
                    {
                    badProfit[m] = k+1;
                     }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
               
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{k+1, 10} {receipts[k], 20} {expenses[k], 20} {profit, 10} ");

           


        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Месяцы с худшей прибылью: {badProfit[0]} , {badProfit[1]}, {badProfit[2]}");


        Console.ReadKey();
    } 
}
```

Вот таким образом я пытаюсь записать данные в массив.

```
if(profit<0)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m <=2;m++)
                    {
                    badProfit[m] = k+1;
                     }
```

А здесь я хочу их вывести вне цикла, что не так?

```
Console.WriteLine($"Месяцы с худшей прибылью: {badProfit[0]} , {badProfit[1]}, {badProfit[2]}");
```

Comment: Ты каждый цикл переписываешь результат одним и тем же значением, т.е.последним. смотри на цикл который 12 раз работает.

Comment: Понял. Не подскажете, как мне это исправить?

Comment: @KirillKulagin вы собственно о чем?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что в твоей программе каждый из месяцев три раза записывается в массив `badProfit`, поэтому самый последний месяц просто перезаписывает предыдущий.

Я бы лучше использовал список для такой задачи, но если важно использовать именно массив, то можно сделать так.

Объявить массив `badProfit` размером 12 и объявить переменную `countBad`, означающую количество месяцев с отрицательной прибылью.

```
    int[] badProfit = new int[12];
    int countBad = 0;
```

В теле главного цикла в теле блока кода, где выполнилось условие отрицательной прибыли добавлять заполнять массив номерами месяцев, когда прибыль отрицательна по индексу - количеству месяцев с отрицательной прибылью, при этом увеличивая каждый раз количество:

```
if (profit < 0)
{
    badProfit[countBad] = k + 1;
    countBad++;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
}
```

А потом просто вывести вот в таком формате:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Месяцы с худшей прибылью: {badProfit[countBad - 3]} , {badProfit[countBad - 2]}, {badProfit[countBad - 1]}");
```

---

Если важно не объявлять дополнительную переменную, или массив всегда должен быть размера 3, то можно написать функцию смещения массива, ну или просто использовать списки.
Это вместо объявления массива:

```
List<int> badProfit = new List<int>();
```

```
if (profit < 0)
{
    badProfit.Add(k + 1);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
}
```

```
Console.WriteLine($"Месяцы с худшей прибылью: {badProfit[badProfit.Count - 3]} , {badProfit[badProfit.Count - 2]}, {badProfit[badProfit.Count - 1]}");
```